# Can't get my text positioned as I want in a circle made with CSS

Tags: html, css

As you can see on this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L9k5c/ my "Hello" text is positionned outside of my red circle instead of centered in it (this is issue 1). Issue 2 is that this "Hello" text makes the "onmouse over" circle not aligned with the red circle anymore.
How could I fix these 2 issues? (for issue 1 I know that I could play with padding and margins but I guess that this would not a clean solution + it would not fix issue 2.
Many thanks

```
<div class="ch-item ch-img-1"><p>hello</p>
    <div class="ch-info">
        <h3>Use what you have</h3>
        <p>by Angela</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ch-item {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    cursor: default;
    box-shadow: 
        inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255,255,255,0.6),
        0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.ch-img-1 { 
    background: red;
}

.ch-info {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(63,147,147, 0.8);
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

}

.ch-info h3 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 30px;
    padding: 45px 0 0 0;
    height: 100px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.ch-info p {
    color: #fff;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-left:80px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0.4s;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0.4s;
}


.ch-item:hover {
    box-shadow: 
        inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
        0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.ch-item:hover .ch-info {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}

.ch-item:hover .ch-info p {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `absolute position` and `transform` to acheive what you want easily.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/L9k5c/6/)

```
.ch-item p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0;
}
```

- P.S - Using `transform` won't work for IE 8 and below, but you're already using it on other places, so I guess it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

**[HERE IS THE UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L9k5c/2/)**

as you are using `position:relative;` in the wrapper so you can use `position:absolute;` to it's inner content to position it

```
.ch-item p{
position:absolute;
top:35%;
left:40%;
}
```

also make `opacity:0` for your hello text whent its hovering..because in your example your hello text is still visible after hover

```
.ch-item:hover p{
opacity:0;
}
```

**[second time modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9k5c/7/)**

Comment: It's will work only for one line with that specific font-size etc.